# Returning RGBA value, instead of Hex with Minicolor JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [minicolor.js](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/) jQuery plugin to select colors for a project I'm working on.  The problem is, even though I have the color picker set to pick alpha colors, it still returns only a 6-digit hex code, and not an 8-digit hex or RGBA

Here is my initialization JS

```
  $(function(){
              $('.color').each(function(){
                    $(this).minicolors({
                    opacity: true,

              });
        });
  });
```

I have seen additions to my code like the following:

```
change: function(hex, opacity) {
    console.log(hex + ' - ' + opacity);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything to my value.

[Here is the website I am working on.](http://alexanderlozada.com/themer/)  As you can see, setting any input to an alpha value will still keep it a 6 digit hex.

I've been stumped on this for a while, and the official documentation isn't very friendly.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you create JSFiddle Demo?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `Function` to convert `Hex` into `RGB Object`, pass your Hex value and return RGB code.

```
function hex2rgb(hex) {
                hex = parseInt(((hex.indexOf('#') > -1) ? hex.substring(1) : hex), 16);
                return {
                        r: hex >> 16,
                        g: (hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8,
                        b: (hex & 0x0000FF)
                };
        }
```

and call this function as:

```
var rgb = hex2rgb('your HEX value');
```

like:

```
var rgb = hex2rgb('#0088cc');
```

Now, You can use your `rgb` object to extract R-G-B values, Like:

```
console.log(rgb.r);
console.log(rgb.g);
console.log(rgb.b);
```

Comment: the problem I'm having is getting the alpha values.

Comment: Please make demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), also try to give desired output and your input.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code will help you.

```
var rgba = '';
$(element).minicolors({
    opacity: true,
    change : function(hex, opacity) {
        rgba = $(this).minicolors('rgbaString');
    },
    hide : function() {
        $(this).val(rgba);
    }
});
```

i created variable to store rgba value, once hide I set the value to input.